# How to generate PDF that is returned to the client using the Prawn gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using prawn gem to generate pdf file,

pdf.render_file('csv.pdf') is saving the file to the project root

instead i want to open the pdf before saving to root, then save it to any location

how to go about it??

thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "open"? open by client with a pdf program?

Comment: yes pdf should open by client, and later saved to desired location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try in the controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf do
    `send_data your_pdf.render, :filename=>"default_filename.pdf", :type=>"application/pdf"`
  end
end
```

where `your_pdf` is the object you created with Prawn.

Comment: i used this code but it take to the blank page                      pdftable = Prawn::Document.new

pdftable.table([["Name","Login"]])

respond_to do |format|
                format.pdf do
              
                  send_data pdftable.render, :filename=>"default_filename.pdf", :type=>"application/pdf"
                end
            end

Comment: Can you check the logs and see if there is any error shown? If so, can you post it here? Which version of Prawn are you using?

Comment: just with this code it works  ' send_data pdftable.render, :filename=>"default_filename.pdf", :type=>"application/pdf" ' skipping the rest. And i added the mimetype in the initializer to make it work.

Comment: I tried the code and it seems to generate valid pdf (Rails 2.3.8, Prawn 0.11.1). You can try rendering before calling `send_data` (so `my_var = pdf.render; send_data my_var, :filename=>..., :type=>...`) and see if it helps. You may also want to restart your application or apache to ensure nothing is cached on the server side, then use CTRL+F5 to reload page without caching on the client side. If nothing helps, I am afraid I have no clue about can be wrong.

Comment: i am using rail3 with ruby 1.9.2 , just with this code it works ' send_data pdftable.render, :filename=>"default_filename.pdf", :type=>"application/pdf" ' skipping the rest. And i added the mimetype in the initializer to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also user prawnto with the inline => false option.